# Aligning images with text

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm having trouble aligning an image with text.  I want my image on the left, and the text inline on the right, centered vertically to the image.

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="icon">
        <img ... />
    </span>
    <span>555-1212</span>
</div>
```

Right now, the text hugs the top of the container.  How can I center it vertically to the middle of the container?

Answer (score 4):

```
.container span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This should do it. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fcv0ng5z/)

Comment: placekitten.com might be my new favorite prototyping resource.

Comment: Heh, I've been using that for years, love that site. Sometimes I use http://www.placecage.com/ when I get tired of kittens.

Comment: This doesn't actually work. Make the image smaller than the text or the text large than the image and you'll see it fail